# Django channel convert to live score board

Tags: ajax, websocket, django-channels

By following Django Channel documentation I successfully ran a simple app that can two way communicate between client and server. I have three pages with a button and variable (c1,c2,c3) respectively and  whose initial values are zero, and one another display page to display all three variables in real-time.

Now I want to update the variable by each client and display them in the display page. Each client will access the page which just have a button whenever they press their variable will be updated by max (c1,c2,c3) +1.  All three clients can independently control their buttons thru individual pages and the result is displayed in real-time.

Any help on this will be appreciated.

My consumer.py:

```
import json
from channels.generic.websocket import WebsocketConsumer
from asgiref.sync import async_to_sync

class ChatConsumer(WebsocketConsumer):
    def connect(self):
        self.room_group_name = 'test'
    async_to_sync(self.channel_layer.group_add)(
        self.room_group_name,
        self.channel_name
    )

    self.accept()


def receive(self, text_data):
    text_data_json = json.loads(text_data)
    message = text_data_json['message']

    async_to_sync(self.channel_layer.group_send)(
        self.room_group_name,
        {
            'type':'chat_message',
            'message':message
        }
    )

def chat_message(self, event):
    message = event['message']

    self.send(text_data=json.dumps({
        'type':'chat',
        'message':message
    }))
```

And my template file is:

```
<h1>Live score</h1>

<form id="form">
    <input type="text" name="message"/>
</form>

<div id="messages"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    let url = `ws://${window.location.host}/ws/socket-server/`

    const chatSocket = new WebSocket(url)

    chatSocket.onmessage = function(e){
        let data = JSON.parse(e.data)
        console.log('Data:', data)

        if(data.type === 'chat'){
            let messages = document.getElementById('messages')

            messages.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', `<div>
                                    <p>${data.message}</p>
                                </div>`)
        }
    }

    let form = document.getElementById('form')
    form.addEventListener('submit', (e)=> {
        e.preventDefault()
        let message = e.target.message.value 
        chatSocket.send(JSON.stringify({
            'message':message
        }))
        form.reset()
    })

</script>
```